# Angular 6 - fullcalendar

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar-4

I'm having issues in integrating fullcalendar with angular 6. I'm using the latest [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular) as reference, however it only works with angular 7. Executing ng serve is giving the following errors:

> ERROR in node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1284,10): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
>
> node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1288,75): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
>
> node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1288,119): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
>
> node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(2250,64): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
>
> node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(2773,74): error TS1122: A tuple type element list cannot be empty.
>
> node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(2779,51): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
>
> node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(2781,9): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
>
> node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(2784,9): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.

Below package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^4.2.1",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.3.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/schematics": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "alertifyjs": "^1.11.4",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.0",
    "ap-angular-fullcalendar": "^1.7.10",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.5.8",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.10.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.1",
    "pg-calendar": "^1.4.30",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.7.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.30",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  }
```

I am not allowed to upgrade to angular 7, Should I install lower version (if there is any) for @fullcalendar/core. I am not sure what to do. 
Can someone please help?

Comment: there's no lower version of the component, no. You'd have to do your own integration